# How to use logging for creating logs of every method call?

Tags: python, logging

I'm writing a CLI app in python for my course at the university. One of the requirements is to write logs from every function/method call during program execution. I need to use the logging module.
The program is a simulation of a wolf chasing sheep, so I have some code to show you:

```py
    class Simulation:
        def __init__(self, init_pos_limit=10.0, sheep_move_dist=0.5,
                     wolf_move_dist=1.0, sheeps_no=50, rounds_no=15,
                     directory='', wait=False
                     ):
            self.sheeps = []
            for i in range(sheeps_no):
                self.sheeps.append(
                    Sheep(init_pos_limit, sheep_move_dist))
            self.wolf = Wolf(wolf_move_dist)
            self.round_no = rounds_no
            self.dir = directory
        
        @property
        def alive_sheeps_no(self):
            return len(self.sheeps) - self.wolf.eaten

        def _sheep_move(self) -> None:
            [sheep.move() for sheep in self.sheeps]
            logging.debug(f"{Simulation.__name__}{self._sheep_move.__name__}() "
                          f"-> None")

        def _wolf_hunting(self) -> int:
            eaten_sheep = self.wolf.take_action(self.sheeps)
            if eaten_sheep != -1:
                self.sheeps[eaten_sheep].alive = False
            logging.debug(f"{Simulation.__name__}{self._wolf_hunting.__name__}() "
                      f"-> {eaten_sheep}")
            return eaten_sheep
```

Here is how I configure logging:

```
if args.log:
    log_path = os.path.join(d['directory'], 'chase' + '.' + 'log')
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_path,
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d :: %(levelname)-8s :: '
                           '%(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                    level=args.log)
```

Of course, I have more classes (e.g. Wolf and Sheep) I also want to log in the same way (need at least function name, call parameters and return value if exist in .log file).
Is there any way to optimize code quantity?

Comment: I see you used a decorator function property. Why not use a decorator function log as well?

Comment: I didn't know I could. Have you any good example for that?